# Legend of the x axis in two Lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

[enter image description here][1]I write because I have a doubt, I need the legend of the graphic to stay in two lines to give more visibility to the graphic. I am trying to add the following code but it does not work

```
[# creamos el gráfico base
ggplot(UNICOS , aes(x = NOMBRE_SERVICIO, y = ID_GESTION_ATENCION)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1)) + 
  stat_pareto(point.color = "blue",   
              point.size = 2,        
              line.color = "black",  
              bars.fill = "#66CCFF")+
  ggtitle("Pareto tipo trámite")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  ylab("Cantidad") +
  xlab("")+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./(max(.) * 0.95) * 100, name = "%Acumulado"))+
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "gray")) -> p

# Armamos las dos graficas
p1 <- p + scale_x_discrete(breaks = UNICOS$NOMBRE_SERVICIO\[1:10\]) + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 10))
```

Comment: You can also flip your plot with `coor_flip()`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What  is "legend of the x axis"? Is it your problem that the x axis categories are vertical (and thus compete with graph space) instead of a horizontal line (possibly hyphenated)? (i.e. simply too long no matter in what direction they are plotted?). You may use abbreviations, or decrease font size to some extent. Second, you may want to give a reproducible example that runs "as is" if copy-pasted (we do not know what "UNICOS" etc. is).

Answer (score 1):

Add `\n` in the x variable names where you want the line breaks:

```
x.labels <- c("Notificación\naudiencia", "extraordinary long\nlong text", "text that cannot\nbe abbreviated\nby any means")
value    <- c(10, 5, 3)
df <- data.frame(x.labels, value)

ggplot(df, aes(fill = 1, y = value, x = x.labels)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]